# Change dropout rate of pre-trained model for inference

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I use Keras and Tensorflow 2.0 and would like to change the dropout rate of a pre-trained model. I tried the following which does not work:

```
model_path = './model_1.h5'
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path)
f = K.function([model.inputs, K.learning_phase(). K.dropout(level=0.9)], [model.outputs])
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Dropout is disabled during inference, it's just a training phase operation.

Comment: @GPhilo I want to use dropout during inference to compute the predicitve uncertainty. Therefore, I would like to enable dropout during inference time. See https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.04977.pdf